# How to get interfaceOrientation property set correctly in view controller hierarchy?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, autorotate

I have a custom view controller hierarchy. 
A sub view controller is added, to a custom parent view controller simply as a subview. The parent view controller also calls the sub view controller's `-[willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:]` and `-[didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:]` methods at the correct time.

Everything seems to work as it should, but for some reason, the `interfaceOrientation` property is not set correctly, it is always `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`.

How do I get the sub view controller to have the correct value in `interfaceOrientation` when I rotate to landscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, not using public APIs anyway. In addition the fact that you are trying to do so suggests that you are not following the recommended design for iOS apps. Consider the advice of the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10)

> Note: If you want to divide a view hierarchy into multiple subareas and manage each one separately, use generic controller objects (custom objects descending from NSObject) instead of view controller objects to manage each subarea. Then use a single view controller object to manage the generic controller objects.

UIViewControllers are intended to manage an entire screen worth of content. Once you violate that assumption you're going to be fighting the framework trying to get your views to behave as you expect.

Comment: the split view controllers on the iPad seem to violate this rule (the parts of the split view are managed by full-fledged view controllers). what if you wanted to implement your own custom split view controller? you can't?

Comment: Correct user102008, right now Apple is able to implement container view controllers but we cannot do the same with public APIs. iOS 5 will change this but until then I would discourage you from trying to show multiple UIViewControllers' views at once. Use generic controller objects instead.