# IOS -Loading Nib View with specific orientation

Tags: ios, rotation, nib

I have a view which is added in the form:  `[currentView addSubview: viewController.view];`

If the view was added like  `[self presentModalViewController: viewController]` then the view is displayed always ok, from landscape and portrait mode.

However, I can't use modal because the view needs to have transparent background and modal converts it to black.

The problem using the first method is that the nib is alway loaded in portrait mode, if the current orientation is portrait everything loads ok, and I can rotate to landscape without problem.

When my device is in landscape mode, the view is loaded as portrait again so it doesn't fit ok in screen.

I tried calling the rotation delegate methods: didRotateWithOrientation, willRotateWithOrientation, willAnimateRotation .. etc., however they don't rotate my view.

Is there any way to load the nib in a specific orientation or to rotate the view before it is added to my other view?

Comment: Do you have code in your view controller to adjust your layout based on orientation? And are you on iOS 5 or 6 (or both)?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche I am trying to avoid that, that will be the last solution. I am trying to use something that already comes with the OS. My app has support iOS > 4.2

Comment: Have you tried "+ (void)attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation" ?

Comment: Is the added viewController's view meant to take up self's entire view? (I think maybe it is, since the reason you gave for not using modal presentation is that you want a transparent background).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think that this is possible, at least in iOS 4.

Check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4869207/472344

You might better off creating a custom view and adding that instead of a view controller.